# how to Hide or Show textField using checkBox in Yii javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox, yii

I have activated my js file in my Yii project view:

```
<?php
/* Register javascript */
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/showHide.js');
?>
```

still in my view, I have a checkBox named 'tbo_sk' and textField named 'nilaiblksk'

```
<?php echo $form->checkBox($model, 'tbo_sk'); ?>
<div style="display: none"><?php echo $form->textField($model, 'nilaiblksk'); ?></div>
```

My question is, how do we make the javascript code in my showHide.js file, to show the textField whenever I check the checkBox, otherwise hide the textField if unchecked?

In my div tag, I'm using the style="display: none" to hide textField.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to give your div an ID or Class, rather than using parent() in jQuery:

```
<div id="hiddenDiv" style="display: none"><?php echo $form->textField($model, 'nilaiblksk'); ?></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#MODELNAME_tbo_sk').change(function(){
        $('#hiddenDiv').toggle(); // or do $('#MODELNAME_nilaiblksk').parent().toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ey thanks, works like a charm!

Back then I thought this wasn't working, until realizing I didn't change the MODELNAME! hahah

Thanks tinyByte!

Answer (score 1):

Then the view file add the following code :

Register a jquery function on document ready to toggle input:

```
$buttonToggler= <<<JS
    toggleInput=function(src,inputName){
      if(src.checked){
        $(src.form[inputName]).removeProp('disabled');
       }else{
         $(src.form[inputName]).prop('disabled','disabled');
       }
    }
JS;
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('toggleFormInputs',$buttonToggler, CClientScript::POS_READY);
```

Add function to checkbox change event:

```
echo $form->checkBox($model,'tbo_sk',
      array('onchange'=>'js:toggleInput(this,"ModelName[nilaiblksk]")'));

echo $form->textField($model,"nilaiblksk");
```

you have to replace actual model name e.g "ModelName[nilaiblksk]" e.g for post model it will be "Post[nilaiblksk]", whatever the actual model you are using.

One more thing , You have to change the toggleInput function e.g if you might only want to make it readonly or add remove css class

Comment: I found an error at the last line of the js:

    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('toggleFormInputs',$buttonToggler, CClientScript::POS_READY);

Isn't that supposed to be placed at view file?

Comment: All the above code will go into view file,just separated the code blocks to make it clear